# add listview item from another form

Tags: c#, listview, invoke

I treid to add item to listview from another form
its the method in form1 (one the listview located)

```css
private void AfterAdd_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            int[] sizes = SellBL.Product.GetProdStockByID(prodid);

            ListViewItem Item = new ListViewItem(prodid.ToString());
            Item.SubItems.Add(prodname);
            Item.SubItems.Add(ebayid);
            Item.SubItems.Add("$" + sellprice);

            if (!isnosize)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < sizes.Length; ++i)
                {
                    if (sizes[i] == 1)
                    {
                        Item.UseItemStyleForSubItems = false;
                        var subItem = Item.SubItems.Add("In Stock");
                        subItem.ForeColor = Color.Green;
                    }
                    else if (sizes[i] == 0)
                    {
                        Item.UseItemStyleForSubItems = false;
                        var subItem = Item.SubItems.Add("Out Of Stock");
                        subItem.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                    }
                    else if (sizes[i] == 2)
                    {
                        Item.UseItemStyleForSubItems = false;
                        var subItem = Item.SubItems.Add("Less Than 3");
                        subItem.ForeColor = Color.Orange;
                    }
                    else if (sizes[i] == 5)
                    {
                        Item.UseItemStyleForSubItems = false;
                        var subItem = Item.SubItems.Add("Less Than 5");
                        subItem.ForeColor = Color.Orange;
                    }
                    else if (sizes[i] == 10)
                    {
                        Item.UseItemStyleForSubItems = false;
                        var subItem = Item.SubItems.Add("Less Than 10");
                        subItem.ForeColor = Color.Orange;
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (sizes[0] == 1)
                {
                    Item.UseItemStyleForSubItems = false;
                    var subItem = Item.SubItems.Add("In Stock");
                    subItem.ForeColor = Color.Green;
                }
                else if (sizes[0] == 0)
                {
                    Item.UseItemStyleForSubItems = false;
                    var subItem = Item.SubItems.Add("Out Of Stock");
                    subItem.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                }
                else if (sizes[0] == 10)
                {
                    Item.UseItemStyleForSubItems = false;
                    var subItem = Item.SubItems.Add("Few Left");
                    subItem.ForeColor = Color.Orange;
                }
            }
            ProductListView.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate () { ProductListView.Items.AddRange(new ListViewItem[] { Item }); }));
        }
```

and it the form2 (from there I wont to add the product)

```css
        private void backgroundWorkerAddProd_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            string a = Addprodnametxt.Text.ToString();
            string b = Addprodebayidtxt.Text.ToString();
            string c = addprodsellpricetxt.Text.ToString();

            f1.AfterProductAdded(1, a, b, c, false);
        }
```

I tried the method: ProductListView.items.add(item);
but it doesnt work
and when I tried this method: ProductListView.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate () { ProductListView.Items.AddRange(new ListViewItem[] { Item }); }));
I got this error:
System.InvalidOperationException: 'Invoke or BeginInvoke cannot be called on a control until the window handle has been created.'

how can I fix it?

thanks

Comment: You need to use an instance of the form when passing data.  See my two form solution : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34975508/reach-control-from-another-page-asp-net

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
  if (System.Windows.Forms.Application.OpenForms["yourForm"] != null)
    {
       (System.Windows.Forms.Application.OpenForms["yourForm"] as Form1).AfterAdd_DoWork();
    }
```